# Alignment of p tag and br tag

Tags: html, css

This is what I want.
[image: This is what I want.]

This is what I'm getting.
[image: This is what I'm getting.]

This is my code. I'm having trouble with the spacing. I can't seem to align p tag with the br tag. I have also tried experimenting with inline but no luck.

```html
<p class="one"><b>Field of</b> Select all that apply, hold CTRL when clicking to select multiple items <br>
  <b>study: </b></p><!-- This is where the issue lies. -->
```

Comment: Knowing what CSS you're applying to it would probably be a good idea. Also the `br` tag is a line-break... it's not clear what you mean by "aligning" to that.

Comment: You're going to need to read up on the basics of HTML and CSS. What you're trying is not even close to the right way to do this, and it's going to cause any answers to either be work-arounds or just writing new code for you.

Comment: I used p{display: inline; word-wrap: break-word;}. Also by alignment I mean in my version the study is directly beneath "Field" but in the original version its slightly ahead. And in my version there's no space between "Field of" and "Select".

Comment: Probably should think about proper HTML markup. What is the actual content you are trying to show.

Comment: Are you trying to make an input form? Consider using a table.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 containers, Left bold text should be in the left container with some styles. There is no good way to fix your code for solving your problem, it is easier to rewrite it at all, as for me.

Use `padding` for having distance between texts and `text-align:right;` for second line to be closer to the border. Take a look:

```css
.main_text {
   padding-left:5px;
}

.left_text {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
   <div class='left_text'>
      <b>Field of <br> study: </b>
   </div>
   <div class='main_text'>
      <label> Select all that apply, hold CTRL when clicking to select multiple items</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple,
Use `float: right` to align "study" correctly. And that's it!
This is your code:

```css
.one {
  width: 55px;
  height: 50px;
}

.span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<b>Field of</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select all that apply; hold CTRL when clicking to select multiple items
<p class="one">
  <b><span class="span">Study:</span></b>
</p>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/abOPJzp?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is perfect for this kind of placement.  Use align-items:center for the first positioning

```css
div{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
font-size:19px;
}

#a1{
display:block;
margin-right:14px;
width:64px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id='a1' ><b>Field of <br/>Study </b></p>
<p>Select all that apply, hold CTRL when clicking to select multiple items </p>
</div>
```

or use align-items:flex-start if you want the placement like this:

```css
div{
display:flex;
align-items:flex-start;
font-size:19px;
}

#a1{
display:block;
margin-right:14px;
width:64px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id='a1' ><b>Field of <br/>Study </b></p>
<p>Select all that apply, hold CTRL when clicking to select multiple items </p>
</div>
```